# JUnit test findById returning null

Tags: spring, junit5

I am trying to write a unit test for a service method (below) and I want to assert that the valued from the repo is not null. But I keep getting null and it is throwing the exception instead. I am not sure where my mistake could be so any help will be appreciated.

Here is the test:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class BookingHistoryServiceImplTest {

    @Mock
    BookingHistoryRepository mockBookingHistoryRepository;

    @Mock
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Mock
    PaymentRepository paymentRepository;

    @Mock
    BookingHistoryRepository bookingHistoryRepository;

    BookingHistoryService bookingHistoryServiceToTest;

    @Mock
    AccommodationRepository accommodationRepository;

    private BookingHistoryEntity testBookingHistoryEntity;
    private AccommodationEntity testAccommodationEntity;
    private UserEntity testUser;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {

        this.testUser = new UserEntity();
        this.testUser.setPassword(TEST_USER_PASSWORD).setFirstName(TEST_USER_FIRST_NAME)
                .setLastName(TEST_USER_LAST_NAME).setEmail(TEST_USER_EMAIL)
                .setRoles(Set.of(new UserRoleEntity().setRole(UserRoleEnum.USER))).setPhoneNumber(TEST_USER_PHONE)
                .setId(TEST_USER_ID);
        // this.userRepository.save(this.testUser);

        this.testAccommodationEntity = new AccommodationEntity();
        this.testAccommodationEntity.setName(TEST_HOTEL)
                .setType(new AccommodationTypeEntity().setType(AccommodationTypeEnum.HOTEL)).setCity(TEST_CITY)
                .setAddress(TEST_ADDRESS).setPostalCode(TEST_PK).setImageUrl(TEST_IMAGE).setId(TEST_HOTEL_ID);

        // this.accommodationRepository.save(this.testAccommodationEntity);

        this.testBookingHistoryEntity = new BookingHistoryEntity();
        this.testBookingHistoryEntity.setBookingTime(LocalDateTime.now()).setCancelled(true).setEmail(TEST_USER_EMAIL)
                .setFirstName(TEST_USER_FIRST_NAME).setCancelledOn(LocalDateTime.now()).setCheckIn(TEST_VALID_CHECKIN)
                .setCheckOut(TEST_VALID_CHECKOUT).setGuest(this.testUser).setLastName(TEST_USER_LAST_NAME)
                .setProperty(this.testAccommodationEntity).setPayment(getPaymentEntity()).setId(1L);

    }
```

In setUp I also have this which was lost in copy/paste

```html
 this.bookingHistoryServiceToTest = new BookingHistoryServiceImpl(this.bookingHistoryRepository, new ModelMapper());
```

```
    @Test
    void find_completed_booking_by_id_should_return_BookingHistoryEntity() {
        Mockito.when(this.mockBookingHistoryRepository.findById(this.testBookingHistoryEntity.getId()))
                .thenReturn(Optional.of(this.testBookingHistoryEntity));

        SummaryBookingServiceModel byId = this.bookingHistoryServiceToTest.findById(TEST_BOOKING_HISTORY_ID);

        System.out.println();
        assertNotNull(byId);
        assertEquals(TEST_BOOKING_HISTORY_ID, byId.getBookingId());
    }
}
```

The Service:

```
@Override
public SummaryBookingServiceModel findCompletedBookingBy(Long id) {
    BookingHistoryEntity bookingHistoryEntity = this.bookingHistoryRepository
            .findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new ObjectNotFoundException("Booking with id " + id + " not found!"));

      return mapToServiceModel(bookingHistoryEntity);
}
```

Exception:

```
com.example.onlinehotelbookingsystem.web.exception.ObjectNotFoundException: Booking with id 1 not found!

    at com.example.onlinehotelbookingsystem.service.impl.BookingHistoryServiceImpl.lambda$findById$4(BookingHistoryServiceImpl.java:119)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:403)
    at com.example.onlinehotelbookingsystem.service.impl.BookingHistoryServiceImpl.findById(BookingHistoryServiceImpl.java:119)
    at com.example.onlinehotelbookingsystem.service.impl.BookingHistoryServiceImplTest.find_completed_booking_by_id_should_BookingEntity(BookingHistoryServiceImplTest.java:141)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:688)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:206)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:65)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:75)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
```

Comment: As I see it, `bookingHistoryServiceToTest` is not instantiated and also the mocked `bookingHistoryRepository` is not set for `bookingHistoryServiceToTest`. Now if you call `bookingHistoryServiceToTest.findById()`, it won't call the mocked repository, which in turn won't return the mocked optional

Comment: Hi, I missed a piece in copy/paste and I added it now.

Comment: What is the value of TEST_BOOKING_HISTORY_ID ?

Comment: The value is private static final Long TEST_BOOKING_HISTORY_ID = 1L;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: you have 2 mocks for BookingHistoryRepository:

1. `mockBookingHistoryRepository`
2. `bookingHistoryRepository`

and you configured the 1st one, but injected into the serviceToTest the 2nd one. So you need to remove one of them. F.e. remove `bookingHistoryRepository` and inject into the serviceToTest `mockBookingHistoryRepository`

And some notes:

1. You should not mock the instance you are testing. You need to remove @Mock here
   `@Mock BookingHistoryService bookingHistoryServiceToTest`
2. You need to inject mocked repositories into the serviceToTest. Like this (or use any other way to set instance fields with mocks)
   `@InjectMock BookingHistoryService bookingHistoryServiceToTest`

Comment: Oh wow, I cannot believe I did that. I looked at it 1000 times. Thank you, I removed bookingHistoryRepository and it works now.